# Remove double Slashes in URL and remove index.php Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, post

thanks for reading my question.

i have an application (php) running on Apache webserver (at the moment on an old apache 2.2.17). Now i will upgrade the Apache to 2.4.18.

For removing the index.php from the url there is an .htaccess file. with this rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

On some requests the application creates post requests like

```
http://www.xyz.yz//targetname/targetname2/
```

double slashes // in the url path.

On Apache 2.2.17 there was no problem with this urls, but Apache 2.4.18 creates an 404 error.

I played lot of  with rewrite rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=307,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

But now the client sends the post request twice. So how can i tell apache "ignore" double quotes without rewrite for example.

Thanks for ideas and solutions.

Answer (score 2):

To remove multiple slashes after the domain extension, you could use the following rule before othe Rules in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //+(.+)\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```

This will convert multiple slashes into one,

- example.com////foo

to

- example.com/foo