# Issue Removing Double Slashes From URL By .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect
https://www.example.es**//**actual/date/
to
https://www.example.es**/**actual/date/

I am try


RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]

but it redirect to

https://www.example.es/**home/website/public_html**/actual/date/

How can i fix this?

Update, it code work fine:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //+(.+)\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
[Remove double Slashes in URL and remove index.php Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649482/remove-double-slashes-in-url-and-remove-index-php-apache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*?public_html\/(.*?)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

That code also doesn't allow me to redirect to
https://www.example.es/actual/date/

Finally, i have managed to solve the problem that created the links with // :D